# Can we Export (as CSV or Excel) the list of modified files using SVN tortoise?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When using the TortoiseSVN → Check For Modifications menu item, I get a list of modified files from the repository with different statuses.

Is there a way to export this list as CSV or Excel or any format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trials, I got to mark the files I need by simple selection and right-click, then select 'copy all information to clipboard'.

Then I opened a new blank excel sheet and pasted the data in the first cell, I got the data properly arranged in the sheet, and each value took a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Check-for-modifications dialog, sort by status. Shift-Click or Ctrl-Click to select all those with "modified" and "added" status. Then simply right-drag the files from the Check-for-modifications dialog to another folder in explorer.

Another way (if you already committed your changes): Show log dialog, select all revisions with the interesting changes. In the lower pane, shift-select all entries, right-click, choose "save as".

Yet another way: Use the repository browser, find the first url (assuming you want to export everything that's changed between two tags, e.g., version 1 and version 2), right-click, "Mark for comparison". Find the second url, right-click, "compare urls". In the following "changed files" dialog, select all files, right-click, choose "export selection to...".

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN has the ability to ***optionally*** install the Subversion command line client. The command line client is guaranteed to be compatible with the GUI client.

That means if you need to save the output of a Subversion command to a file, you can always use the command line client:

```
C:> svn status > status.txt
```

I highly recommend that you install the command line client the next time you upgrade your TortoiseSVN installation. The command line client makes it easy to parse Subversion output for all sorts of reasons, and can be easily integrated into Python, Perl, or PowerShell scripts.